# UISegmentedControl Selected Tint Not Showing

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

The tint that usually shows on a `UISegmentedControl` on the selected button isn't showing when I set the whole nav bar to black (`self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];`).

Is this a bug or something I'm missing?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

In order for the tint color to show, there are a couple of requirements:

```
segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
```

It's required for the `tintColor` to work.

You also mention that you have the `tintColor` set to `[UIColor blackColor]`.  Unfortunately, the `UISegmentedControl` will always display the selected segment with a **darker** color, never a lighter.  Try setting your `tintColor` to `[UIColor darkGrayColor]` and you should be able to see the selected segment change color.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried setting the tint on the segmented control separately?

```
segmentedControl.tintColor = self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using tint color `[UIColor colorWithWhite:80.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]`.
This makes the black color less black and allows the selected segment to become darker after selection. You can set the white component as suitable.

Sample code:

```
UISegmentedControl *aSegmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:arrItems];
aSegmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(55, 382, 210, 32);
aSegmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
aSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
aSegmentedControl.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:80.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
```

Answer (score 2):

On iphone 3.0, if you want add the Segmented Control in a NavigationController, do that first and change the tintcolor after u did that.

Comment: This is helpful, but in my case I was setting the segmented control into the navitem in viewDidLoad and then immediately setting the tint color.  I found I had to move the tintColor set to viewWillAppear and then it finally worked.

Answer (score 2):

If you are seeing different tint colors on the nav bar, you may also want to use the momentary property on your uisegmentedcontrol.

`segmentedControl.momentary=YES;`

This clears the highlight tint from the control.

Answer (score 1):

Change the segmented control style to Bar or Bezeled in the Attributes Inspector. That's all.